# Need help with employee with poor attitude

Tags: teamwork, leadership, motivation

I have an team mate that I work with as a territory sales rep.  As a position that is expected to work as a lateral leader and without authority, our mutual management team had tasked me with coming up with a targeting business plan and a mechanism of accountability that our team could use between us weekly.  When I forward this email to my coworker and asked what they thought of these targets and what they felt would be a good mechanisms for us to report back to our management team, the following ensued..

1. The coworker said that it just make no sense how I don't have any visits to certain targets.

   - when it comes to targets driving our business I asked how come they don't have any visits to these other targets.
   - while on the call with the coworker I looked at the targets they were referring to and they didn't have any visits either.
2. the moment I challenge the coworker in the same manner they state, "see this is exactly what I didn't want to happen"
3. The coworker begins to state how big of a waste of time this is and that the targets chosen are nothing different that what they have always been and that we should not have to develop and "accountability" plan.
4. He rants about how he was demoted to a lower position, which happened during a merger and he kept his job because the position was eliminated.
5. He rants about how he is tired of doing everybody else work.
6. Coworker rants about not making into the next phase of a leadership class that requires subjective judgment and performance by our leadership team.
7. Upon trying to redirect the conversation back to the reason this conversation even started which was to creat a mutual target plan and create a weekly mechanism of accountability between us that has to be turned into our management team, he is still reluctant to assist in the task completion and states that his direct manager, even though our managers are different this was an assignment that they agreed upon, said that all he has to do is send me a list of names and give feedback once a week and that our call tracking system we use will serve as his mode of communication.

I could go on.  How can I help my coworker?  I know this is somewhat difficult to see the whole scenario in this medium of communication but is there something else or some way differently I could have approached this conversation?  I have not approached management yet.

Comment: May I ask why the community had downvoted this? It seems like an open enough question, no ranting, and could possibly be of use to others.

Comment: Points 1, 2 and to an extent 3; it sounds like he gave you some specific reasons why he thinks your plan is flawed.  What more did you want from him?  Were you expecting him just to agree to whatever you decided?  If so, why even ask his opinion if you're not going to take it on board?

Comment: OK, 1, 2 and 3 are honest, if raw, answers for the question you asked. If you didn't want these answers, why have you asked? 4 is just natural, you don't demote people and expect them to be happy. 5 - is it true? Any idea why he feels that way? 6 - he was demoted and then someone's subjective decision stopped him from promotion - again, natural. 7. Is it true? Is he only doing what his manager told him? If that's true, why do you have any problem with him instead of the management?

Answer (score 4):

> How can I help my coworker? I know this is somewhat difficult to see
>   the whole scenario in this medium of communication but is there
>   something else or some way differently I could have approached this
>   conversation? I have not approached management yet.

You probably should have talked face-to-face about this task with your coworker rather than sending emails. That way, you could have empathized a bit about your coworker's feelings but gotten back on track quicker, rather than just seeing a long rant unfold.

But if you aren't successful trying to redirect the conversation to the mutual task at hand, you must bump the problem to your manager. It's not your job to fix your coworker's attitude.

I have no idea what a "lateral leader without authority" can be expected to accomplish without cooperation in your company, but that's for your boss (and perhaps his boss) to decide.

Comment: Thank you for your advice as I am seeking several sources of advice because this type of behavior is pushing 10months now.  Not only is it impacting my responsibilities but it is also impacting others on the team.